# Dozer - empty object instead of null

Tags: java, dozer, sourceforge

In dozer how do i globally initialize values to empty object instead of null

For ex:

```
Class Person
{
public Address address;
//getters and setters for address

}

Class Address
{
String addressField1;
String addressField2;
}
```

Similarly I have objects PersonVO and AddressVO which are similar to Person and Address

After mapping the values using the dozer, if address value is null in Person object, than the result in `personvo.getAddressVO.getAddressField1()` will throw *null pointer exception*, is there any way to avoid this?

If I use custom converters than i would end up in doing typical way of setting values in custom converters and would defeat the purpose of using the dozer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to initialize the destination object in Dozer.

1. Define a factory class for the destination Object.
2. Specify the create-method for the destination object as the method in the above factory class.

Take your example, I presume you want to map Person to PersonVO and Address to AddressVO.

Create a factory class for PersonVO

```
public abstract class PersonVOFactory {
    private PersonVOFactory() {
    }
    public static PersonVO createPersonVO() {
        PersonVO personVO = new PersonVO();
        personVO.setAddressVO(new AddressVO());
        return personVO;
    }
}
```

Specify the above create method for Person to PersonVO mapping.

```
<mapping map-id="person-mapping">
    <class-a>Person</class-a>
    <class-b create-method="PersonVOFactory.createPersonVO">PersonVO</class-b>
    <field>
        <a>address.addressField1</a>
        <b>addressVO.addressField1</b>
    </field>
    <field>
        <a>address.addressField2</a>
        <b>addressVO.addressField2</b>
    </field>
</mapping>
```

Now the statement, `personvo.getAddressVO.getAddressField1()` will not throw an NPE.

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify the setter method of the `PersonVO` class, you could do as follow :

```
public void setAddressVO(AddressVO address) {
    this.addressVO = address == null ? new AddressVO() : address;
}
```

Thus you will be sure that the field `addressVO` is never `null`.

Please note that this is rather dirty because :

1. if a person has no address, his address field should be `null`
   rather than an empty `AddressVO` object.
2. a customized setter like
   this is a bad practice as most users of your class would expect the
   set method to set the value and do nothing more. You can optionally
   create a new method `initAddressVO` and call this method from dozer
   using the `set-method` attribute in the configuration file.

It would be much better (if it's possible) to check if address is null with some `if` to avoid the `NullPointerException`.

Comment: i had similar idea, problem with checking for null is that, the code which is going to access `personvo.getAddressVO().getAddressField1()` is an generated code from some tool and i am not sure whether it has option of having generating the null check.

Answer (score 0):

Object which do not have any non-static data member is called empty Object because all the non static data member reside inside object in heap. So if we don't have have any non-static data member, we have object as empty. but not NULL.

Empty Object:
Object which do not have any non-static data member.

Null Object:
Object which do not have any reference i.e. null reference;